# Permutation Models of Set Theory - meaning of "ZFA does not distinguish between atoms"

Tags: set-theory

Halbeisen Combinatorial Set Theory on page 169 states "ZFA does not distinguish between the atoms and so a permutation of the set of atoms induces an automorphism of the universe".

How does the inability to determine the truth or falsity of "atom a = atom b = atom c = atom d" (assuming thats what the above means) affect the ability of ZFA to determine whether, for example,

{a} = {b}

or

{a,1}={b,1}

or

{a,b}={c,d}

To do this appears to require only the use of the $\in$ relation in the modified extensionality axiom (A is the set of atoms):

$\forall$x$\forall$y ((x $\notin$ A $\land$ y $\notin$ A) $\implies$ $\forall$z(z $\in$ x $\iff$ z $\in$ y) $\implies$ x=y)

The "Axiom of Atoms" suggests the $\in$ relation can be used on atoms, so can $\in$ not distinguish between atoms, e.g. to determine whether {a}={b}, is "a $\in$ {b}" not false?

Comment: None of the things you wrote down are sentences in ZFA (at least not without further elaboration of what abbreviations are happening). What is this $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen. The a,b,c,d are atoms, hence "atom a = atom b etc. which I was trying to define a,b,c,d as atoms.

Comment: Yes I got what you were going for but do you see the issue now? If we have an axiom that implies there is more than one atom, we are free to say “let $a$ and $b$ be distinct atoms...” in which case we have assumed, so can certainly prove $a\ne b.$ But you can’t be any more specific about “which atoms” and that’s the real issue. And referring to below, no, when you add an axiom saying $A$ is countably infinite, you do just that, you don’t add constants to the language. In general there’s a lot of syntax vs semantics issues here.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - yes, thanks, I see the issue - my eyes are opened from the responses. To follow up I am investigating definability & the syntax vs semantics issues associated with the knowledge difference between the metatheory & internal to the ZFA model, including what "the set of atoms is countably infinite" means (& what the metatheory and ZFA model think the statement says and what expressions it can determine are true / false). Maybe "The set of Atoms is countable" doesn't mean exists a function (both in the Metatheory and in the ZFA model) f : ω --> A ......

Comment: “The set of atoms is countable” means precisely that there is a bijection $\omega\to A$ in the model. The thing is that any such bijection, or even injection, won’t be symmetric (with respect to the group and normal filter chosen), so won’t be in the symmetric sub-model.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen. OK thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZFA is a formal system whose language is almost as spare as that of ZF. When you write down an expression with constants in it and ask if ZFA proves it, it's on you to explain how to actually define those constants in ZFA, and thus form a bona-fide sentence in ZFA's language. I suspect if you try that with some of the expressions you've written above, you won't have much luck, and, well, this is one way to understand what is meant by ZFA not distinguishing between the atoms.

Intuitively, within a model of ZF, we can take any set and unroll it into its transitive closure: make a with the set at its root, its elements at the next level, its elements' elements at the next level, and so on. Well-foundedness implies that after a finite number of levels, everything has terminated at sets with no elements. Extensionality implies each of these leaves are the empty set and working recursively back upwards we see that extensionality requires us to identify any two sets whose tree above is structurally identical. Any automorphism of the set will need to extend to an automorphism of this graph, since it was just built by the membership relation, so will need to map structurally identical subgraphs onto structurally identical subgraphs, and as we just said, these are necessarily the same set, so this action is trivial.

But when we allow atoms, no longer is every leaf necessarily the empty set, so the sets in the graph can no longer be distinguished only by the shape of the tree above: now we need to know which atoms are at the leaves as well. When we permute the atoms on the leaves, it results in a (possibly) distinct, but structurally identical set, so acts as an $\in$-automorphism of the set's transitive closure.

Note, there is morally nothing distinguishing the empty set from an atom (just as there is nothing morally distinguishing the various zeros in Asaf's analogy) , since they are just possible objects that go at the leaves (i.e. objects with no elements). The only thing that distinguishes is the fact that we have put the empty set into our language, so now any automorphism of a model must fix it by definition. You can think of the empty set as just an atom that's been distinguished as 'pure' by fiat, and the pure sets are the ones where all the leaves of their transitive closure is the empty set. We have not made any further distinctions amongst the atoms, and hopefully seeing how this aligns with the formalism closes the loop between my first paragraph and the long digression afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Not distinguishing between the atoms does not mean that they are equal, or that we somehow cannot tell in a given model if two atoms are equal.

Two things are equal if *and only if* they are the same thing. Two different atoms are not the same thing, so they are clearly not equal.

However, if we want to distinguish between two sets, we only need to examine their elements. In the case of atoms, this is not true anymore. Atoms have no elements.<sup>1</sup> So there is no way to distinguish between two atoms by investigating the $\in$ relationship "below them". Since modern set theory, in the form of theories related to $\sf ZF$, put *a lot* of weight into well-foundedness, this is also true here.

One can look at this as some sort of a "computable way of distinguishing things". In the natural numbers, if we want to compare two natural numbers, without knowing a lot about them, we only need to start asking if both are greater than $0$, or $1$, or $2$, etc. and at some point one of them will give a negative answer, so it is not larger than $k$. If the other is *also* not larger than $k$, then the two numbers are equal, otherwise the one is smaller than $k$ and the other one is not. (Note that the key point is that we have a concrete description of $0,1,2,\dots$, but our two numbers are somehow more... abstract.)

In that way, $=$ can be computed from $<$. And we want it to be computed from $\in$ in a similar way. Atoms violate this. Imagine the natural numbers with several different $0$'s, each spawning its own copy of what you'd normally thing about the natural numbers, and these copies also mix together in some coherent way. But you're building everything "upwards". You can still compare any non-$0$ objects, but between the different $0$s it's impossible to say which one is which. And that is what Halbeisen means.

---

Footnotes.

1. Sometimes $\varnothing$ is referred to as an atom, but in this context we mean "non-set atoms"; or in the Quine sense, that $x=\{x\}$ is an atom, as those can serve for the same purpose as the atoms in $\sf ZFA$.

Comment: @ Asaf & spaceisdarkgreen. OK, the ZFA axioms, which based upon what you describe, don't say what the atoms are - they just say there is a set A with atoms in it and the membership relation can't distinguish them based upon their contents. Later on Halbeisen then describes what is in the set of atoms by saying on p171 "A is a countable infinite set". I just assumed that this then 'automatically' adds to the formal ZFA language (1) a countable infinite set of constants, each referring to each atom in A and (2) along with a countably infinite set of expressions {ai≠aj}.

Comment: @ Asaf & spaceisdarkgreen. From the previous comment, hence the language ZFA1 :=  "ZFA + countable constants for atoms + {ai≠aj}" knows about each atom and it knows that they aren't the same using the equality '=' relation. However as expressions in this language are finite, the only definable sets of atoms will be the minimal definable set described in "Hodges A Shorter Model Theory" (e.g. page 27 Theorem 2.1.2), which means any definable set of atoms in ZFA1 would be finite / cofinite sets of atoms. Looking to the Basic Fraenkel Model in Halbeisen page 171 this actually occurs in Lemma 7.2.

Comment: @ Asaf & spaceisdarkgreen. So would the above two comments be a possible deduction from your kind responses ?

Answer (score 1):

"Distinguish", here, is in the sense of a predicate that can be used to discriminate between different things.

As an example, in ZF, we can distinguish the empty set from other sets by writing the predicate

- $P(x) \equiv \forall y : y \notin x $

The empty set is the only set which satisfies this predicate, and so we can say that the language of set theory can distinguish between the empty set and nonempty sets.

Similarly, in ZFA, if we take a *parameter* $a$ that refers to an atom, we can write down a predicate on atoms

- $Q_a(b) \equiv (a = b) $

Then the predicate $Q_a$ can distinguish between atoms that are $a$ and atoms that are not $a$.

The key thing to note here is that $Q_a$ has a free parameter $a$, so it is qualitatively different from the example of $P$ above which didn't have any free parameters.

What Halbeisen is saying is that if $R$ is any predicate in the language of ZFA that doesn't have any parameters, then $R$ cannot be used to distinguish between atoms. That is, $R(a) \equiv R(b)$ for all atoms $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have not actually read the explicit formulation of ZFA. But this is how this sort of thing goes in other contexts and I presume it's accurate here.

Comment: Neat & Thanks - I will follow up on the use of parameters in ZF. Out of interest would my related comment be correct, which looks related to your nice answer : [Later on Halbeisen then describes what is in the set of atoms by saying on p171 "A is a countable infinite set". I just assumed that this then 'automatically' adds to the formal ZFA language (1) a countable infinite set of constants, each referring to each atom in A and (2) along with a countably infinite set of expressions {ai≠aj}.] ?